# SD card v1.0 CMD8 command reply

Tags: microcontroller, spi, sd

I use Elm Chan's FAT32 library with custom initialisation code for SD managemnt with STM32. I have a bunch of 512Mb-2Gb SD cards that I wanna utilize in hardware. I noticed strange behavior with some of the cards.
According to Elm's code we should issue CMD8 command to check the card's type: 1.0/1.1 or 2.0+

512Mb cards give me

```
CMD0 OK
sdc_cmd: CMD8
Spi::assert
R: 0xFF
R: 0x5
```

Which is illegal command + idle - OK

1Gb/2Gb cards give me

```
CMD0 OK
sdc_cmd: CMD8
Spi::assert
get_response:
R: 0xFF
R: 0x1
CMD8 OK
SDHC detected
SD v2
```

after standart initiation I issue

```
sdc_cmd: CMD16
Spi::assert
get_response: expecting 0x1
R: 0xFF
R: 0x1
Block size was set to 512
SD init OK
Spi::highspeed
disk_read: Drive=0, sector=0,
Sdc::read_block, Address=0, BlockSize=1
sdc_cmd: CMD17
Spi::assert
get_response: expecting 0x0
R: 0xFF
R: 0x1
```

So it does not respond to CMD17 as I expected. 
In Windows all 2Gb cards works OK and detected as SD, not SDHC.

The question:

1) Why 2Gb card behaves like v2.0?
2) What to do in this case? Where I made mistake in the init process?

The code is [here](https://github.com/Pugnator/CoreTex/blob/master/firmware/src/drivers/storage/sdc.cc) 
SDC_Error Sdc::initialize(void)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Why 2Gb card behaves like v2.0?

Almost all 2 GB cards are newer than the 2.0 SD card spec, and thus support the newer commands. But they still run in SD mode - the 32 bit address is measured in bytes and not in 512 byte blocks.

Only SDHC cards >= 4GB use 512 byte block addresses.

> 2) What to do in this case?

Set the block size to 512 bytes and use the card as any other SD card.

> Where I made mistake in the init process?

You should use the elaborate SD card initialisation that is shipped with FATFS instead of trying to roll your own.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried to study the internal processes. If you want to know how something works - hack it :)